# MVC3 Model Data Population

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am using Code First So it created the entities and generated dbsets and using LINQ to achieve my data. I am new to LINQ I want to know the following

this is my one table my model

```
namespace MISSanctions.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class tbl_navigation_menus
{
    public long tbl_nav_id { get; set; }
    public string tbl_controller { get; set; }
    public string tbl_method { get; set; }
    public string tbl_menu_name { get; set; }
    public long tbl_parent_id { get; set; }
    public string tbl_view { get; set; }
    public long tbl_child_id { get; set; }
    public byte tbl_active { get; set; }
  }
}
```

It has a relation with a table tbl_nav_rights

```
 namespace MISSanctions.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class tbl_nav_rights
{
    public long tbl_nav_right_id { get; set; }
    public long tbl_user_id { get; set; }
    public long tbl_nav_id { get; set; }
    public long tbl_nav_active { get; set; }
}
}
```

I want to select the rights of tbl_user_id is 11796 .Means 11769 will be having multiple rights and I want to join the Table with the above tbl_navigation_menus which holds the navigation name controller name and method and some icon images.

I want to create a separate model which returns me the data of the user id 11769. I am creating a Model like this but confused how to fetch the multiple rows in a model

this is the main navigation model which will be returned to the view

```
namespace MISSanctions.Models
{
public class AdminNavigationList
{
    public int Userid {get;set;}
    public int tbl_nav_id{get;set;}
    public string tbl_controller { get; set; }
    public string tbl_method { get; set; }
    public string tbl_menu_name { get; set; }
    public int tbl_parent_id { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string tbl_icon { get; set; }
}

}
```

Then i will loop through to display the navigation.. Please help me to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ones you have to set relation of tbl_nav_menus table with tbl_nav_rights 
and nav_menu table contains multiple entries for nav_right table,
then you have to add

public partial class tbl_navigation_menus
{
   public Ilist tbl_nav_rights{get;set;}

}

check it onces..